# How to write a function that generates numbers periodically using triangle wave formula?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a function that generates numbers between a minimum and a maximum value  periodically that have a triangle wave form such as the Link the example in the link :
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave][1]

but i am not aiming to draw the line i just need the Y values

```
public float TriangleFunction(int time, float min, float max, int period)
    {
        return (max - min) / 2 / period * (period - Math.Abs(time % (2 * period) - period)) + (max + min) / 2;
    }
Values = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(index => Class1.TriangleFunction2(time++,0,1000, 6)).ToList()
```

This formula does generate the numbers correctly, but I can't seem to figure out what to use for the time value in a way that keeps it incrementing, and sets back to zero when a timer stops

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what you want, and what you are getting instead?

Comment: `time` (passed to the method call) is a variable somewhere in your code that is not shown in this snippet. So it's unclear what you mean by "back to zero"

Comment: Can't you use `index` instead of your `time`?

Comment: You may want to look into `yield return`